# How to do column level search in ant-design using function component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using function component and  to draw the table I'm using ant-design. Now I want to do column search for each column present in table

I tried this
https://ant.design/components/table/

It's a class component I got bit confused. Can anyone suggest how to search column level search in ant design table using function component?

Thanks

Comment: React components are react components, they can have state, and have props. Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the confusion? What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

just to complement the previous answer: searchInput is a resp, in class component it is automatic but in function you have to do the following:

```
....

      const searchInput = useRef(null);

....

    <Input
        ref={searchInput}

....

    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
                if (visible) {
                    setTimeout(() => searchInput && searchInput.current && searchInput.current.select())
                }
            }

.....
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be this way, sorry if i forgot to replace a this. I followed the antd table API here https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel

```js
const {  Table, Input, Button, Space  } = antd;
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';
const {  SearchOutlined  } = icons;

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    name: 'Jim Red',
    age: 32,
    address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
  },
];

const App = () => {
  
  const [state, setState] = useState({searchText:'', searchedColumn:''})
  
  const handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    confirm();
    setState({
      searchText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedColumn: dataIndex,
    });
  };

  const handleReset = clearFilters => {
    clearFilters();
    setState({ searchText: '' });
  };
  
  const getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
    filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={node => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
          onPressEnter={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
          style={{ marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={() => handleReset(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
            Reset
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="link"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => {
              confirm({ closeDropdown: false });
              setState({
                searchText: selectedKeys[0],
                searchedColumn: dataIndex,
              });
            }}
          >
            Filter
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        ? record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
        : '',
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => searchInput.select(), 100);
      }
    },
    render: text =>
      state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[state.searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ''}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      ),
  });

  
    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        width: '30%',
        ...getColumnSearchProps('name'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        key: 'age',
        width: '20%',
        ...getColumnSearchProps('age'),
      },
      {
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
        key: 'address',
        ...getColumnSearchProps('address'),
        sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
        sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
      },
    ];
    
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is searchInput ? I'm getting this error Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'searchInput')